# Getting audio from the folder

Tags: android, audio, media-player, alarmmanager

I have an alarm and want to give the choice to user choose the music.
I have an activity with some code, include this fragment:

```
Button ring_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
ring_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent_for_ring_button = new Intent();
        intent_for_ring_button.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        File file = new File(REPORTS_DIRECTORY);
        intent_for_ring_button.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"audio/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent_for_ring_button,"Open folder"), 0);
    }
});
```

and one more activity with alarm that extends **BroadcastReceiver**, where i`m starting next activity with dialog window with some music.
Here is it:

```
public class Dialog_window extends ActionBarActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_window_bckg);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        final MediaPlayer Alarm_mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(Dialog_window.this, R.raw.data_don_t_sing);
        Alarm_mp3.start();
        Alarm_mp3.setLooping(true);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dialog_window.this);
        builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
                .setMessage("Вставай!")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.uncle_sam)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("ОК, встаю, встаю.",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                Alarm_mp3.stop();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

How i can realize this? I must get some extras from the first activity or smth else?

Comment: If understand correctly, your problem is to transfer the selected file from one activity/fragment to another?

Comment: @cylon yes it is. and use this file with MediaPlayer class

Answer (score 0):

After you called `startActivityForResult` with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent, you should overwrite `onActivityResult` in the same class, and get the chosen file's path. After you have the path, you can save to shared preferences, and easily retrieve from another activity (ex. in your `Dialog_window`) and play with `MediaPlayer`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 0){ // you've set to 0 at startActivityForResult 
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
            // save filePath to shared preferences
       }
   }
 }
```

After you retrieved inside another activity, just simply play it.

```
String savedPath = ..... ; // retrieve from shared preferences  

//check your saved path, it could be a full path already..
//if it is, you don't need to concatenate anything to it
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+savedPath;

mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fullPath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();   
mediaPlayer.start()
```

**Saving file path to shared preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("audioFilePath", filePath);
editor.commit();
```

**Restoring file path from shared preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredFilePath = prefs.getString("audioFilePath", null);
if (restoredFilePath != null) {
  // here you have the restored file path
}
```

Comment: i've tried it, but nothing is playing. may be i've not correct save my filepath to SharedPreferences? how i can do it correctly?

Comment: I added an example how to save and restore the file path. Please add a log before saving the filePath to shared pref and also after restoring it. Lets see if everything was ok. Post it here the values. Also check your logcat, check if the media player has threw an exception